# Rails 5 partial only rendering within certain views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I have a partial that holds a button. I have some business logic written around the button so that it becomes active/inactive for certain users etc..

I have rendered this partial successfully in one view but I have added again in two other places and I get this error:

```
Missing partial app/views/borrowers/shared/_create_campaign_button.html.erb with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/donal/Desktop/flenderProject/flender/app/views"
  * "/home/donal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-core-1.0.1/app/views"
  * "/home/donal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #11):
9
10
11
12
13
14


      <%  if @user.present? #if @user.is_irish? && @user.is_business?  %>
        <%= render 'app/views/borrowers/shared/create_campaign_button.html.erb' %>
      <% end %>

      <ul>

Rails.root: /home/donal/Desktop/flenderProject/flender

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/campaigns/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_campaigns_index_html_erb__4376944130783067979_70279893678640'
app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:64:in `index'
Request
Parameters:

None
```

Comment: Try removing `.html.erb` at the end of file when rendering.

Comment: Didn't work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<%= render 'app/views/borrowers/shared/create_campaign_button.html.erb' %>
```

with

```
<%= render 'borrowers/shared/create_campaign_button' %>
```

It is searching for the partial in *app/views*, so you don't need to add it to the file path.

Comment: This worked thanks @JagdeepSingh I will accept this in a few minutes